# Eclipse apagou todo meu projeto

Tags: eclipse

Eu tenho um projeto no workspace, e então fui em importar o projeto no Eclipse quando importou, ele zerou todos os arquivos, e apagou imagens e tudo do projeto, é possível recuperar?

Answer (score 5):

Diretamente no Eclipse não. Pra recuperar precisa dar um undelete nos arquivos. Pra isso desligue imediatamente seu computador, melhor se for direto no botão sem ir no desligar, retire seu HD de dentro do computador e coloque como escravo (HD secundário) em outra máquina. Uma vez feito isso use uma dos muitos softwares de undelete existentes. Os passos acima são necessários pq o espaço dos arquivos  uma vez disponibilizado pro S.O. pode ser regravado com outra coisa. Quanto mais operações forem feitas, maior a probabilidade de seus arquivos serem sobrescritos. O hd principal normalmente é muito gravado com as atividades normais do S. O. por isso a necessidade de colocar como escravo antes de começar o procedimento de undelete.  Também se projeto for grande a probabilidade de recuperação de todos os arquivos diminui.